# Using RedisCache Class & Methods

Tags: plugin-development, cache, php

How would I access the available `RedisCache` class and it's properties/methods in PHP/plugins? (https://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/etc/cache/RedisCache)

I'm just starting to learn Redis and can't seem to find more information about how to start using the available class. I have set [cacheMethod](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#cacheMethod) to `redis`, and created a `rediscache.php` file in `craft/config/`.

I want to explore connecting to db, inserting my own keys/values and retrieving data for my other plugins, but can't seem to find the right path path. I tried things like:

```
echo craft()->redisCache->hostname;
```

But that returns `CExeption` errors. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put your Redis connection information in your `craft/config/rediscache.php` config file.  You can see the default [here](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/etc/config/defaults/rediscache.php), and your file will override any matching set keys.

From there you can use `craft()->cache->set()`, `craft()->cache->get()` and any other cache methods on Yii's [CCache](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/framework/caching/CCache.php) class.

Comment: I should've known...! Don't know what I'd do without you sometimes. Thanks, Brad!